# How do I crawl a page using JS for internal links ? It has to be done recursively as well

Tags: javascript, recursion, web-crawler, internal-link

So basically, the task is to crawl the web page using JavaScript and when I find the internal links, I should find the internal links in each of them as well and it has to go as many levels 'deep' as it needs.
Please share any ideas.

Comment: Look at `wget` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a browser extension to do that. JS is limited to the given Dom.